# How to create a numeric keypad in VB 2008

Tags: numeric, keypad

I am developing a calculator app for Windows. I want to create a numeric keypad that has ONLY numbers and the decimal points. How do I create one and pop it up whenever the user selects ANY textbox?

Thanks and Regards,
S Sandeep

Comment: I tried creating a dialog, but didn't work out....

Comment: This is about three chapters in a learning VB book, and three careful readings. Don't even know where to start.

Comment: If you would be able to answer it at the shortest possible time, I'd be grateful...

Comment: Which bit? How to create a form? Surely you know how to do that. How to add an OnEnter eventhandler. Raising a modal dialog? The question is too broad.

Comment: Well, will it work out if you add the keys as buttons in the side of the form and then code it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess I got the answer myself:

I added two boolean variables in the form declarations called yesfocusedtxtno1 and yesfocusedtxtno2. I used them in the GotFocus() method of both textboxes and kept changing the variables accordingly. For example if txtno1 has the focus, I say yesfocusedtxtno2 = False and yesfocusedtxtno1 = true. Then I added this code in the OnClick method of each button in the keypad. (I've just given one for sample.)

```
Dim keynum As String = "1"
    If yesfocusedtxtno1 = True Then
        txtNo1.Focus()
        txtNo1.Text = txtNo1.Text + keynum
    Else
        txtNo2.Focus()
        txtNo2.Text = txtNo2.Text + keynum
    End If
```

Comment: I'm pleased for you. Though I've got to say your answer makes as much sense as your question.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, sir. If you think you can give a better answer, please do...

Comment: I feel like I'm playing the quiz game jeopardy, poorly. Can't figure out the question the answer you have provided is to. Certainly can't relate it to one you asked.